# How to handle this PHP encoding issue?

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm using PHP to grab some JSON from this URL - [goo.gl/xdIqEy](http://goo.gl/xdIqEy)

I've tried using `cURL` and `file_get_contents()`, but the 'LastName' element always comes back looking like `─Éur─æi─ç`

If I view that URL in Chrome, it looks like `ÄurÄ‘iÄ‡`

It should look like `Đurđić`

It's obviously some kind of encoding issue, but how to I handle this? The HTTP response headers don't give any clues to the encoding type.

I've tried a lot of different `iconv` combinations when I've got the string back in PHP - but no luck.

If I go to that URL in IE, it let's me download the .json file to disk. When I open that in Sublime Text, it looks correct.

Any advice?

Comment: Not sure if it would matter, but are your PHP files saved in UTF8 encoding or just ANSI?

Comment: What ever you are using to display the date has to support utf-8, utf8_decode converts utf-8 to latin1 but latin1 doesn't support those characters so they are replaced with question marks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo iconv("utf-8", "latin1", "BosanÄiÄ‡");//Bosanči
echo iconv("utf-8", "latin1", "JirÃ¡Äek"); //Jiráček
?>
```

Your input charset is UTF-8 you need to convert back to latin1

Comment: I can't specify the 'Content-Type' in the header unfortunately. I'm calling a 3rd party web service with CURL from my PHP script - and there's no 'Content-Type' set in the response headers.

Comment: I did try setting `CURLOPT_ENCODING` in my CURL request, but I'm getting the same issue.